# Just started a new job, but it's not meeting my expectations, also just found out I am pregnant

Tags: new-job, expectations, pregnancy

Two weeks ago I started as a Front-End Developer in a new company. On the interview we discussed my experience in Javascript and VueJS. React and C# was also on the table, but I said have zero experience with it, just basic knowledge.

**The problem:** Things in this new company are not good at all, and I just realized I am pregnant. I am also on a 6 month trial period. I have a feeling they might not continue my contract, because:

- Very soon I'll have to go on maternity leave.
- I feel like I'm not gonna meet their expectations.
- Company seems to be in a small crisis because of the COVID19.

**Why not meeting each others expectations:**

- I was assigned on a C# MVC project. I have zero experience with it and I find it very hard working on this project. One small task takes me way too much time. I have to learn on the go.
- I was expecting good work process, but the other coworkers seem not very experienced and not knowing what's going on. No good leader to rely on.

**Bad things about the company so far:**

- The on-boarding process was awful. Zero documentation and the person assigned to help me had no interest in doing it at all.
- In the lunch breaks, all coworkers were complaining about the company.
- They don't have projects for my expertise and assigned me on a C# MVC project. I feel like I'm junior dev again.
- The people in my team are also "newbies" - The PM started 2 months ago. The other devs has 1 year or less experience in the company.
- Company announced cut offs, because of the virus. Some coworkers have to work on 4 hours and -50% salary. Traveling expenses, food and other goodies will be cut.

I realized I don't want to work for this company, but I don't have a choice. 
**What measures I can take to make sure they will continue my contract? How to cope with the pressure (from the problems I've listed) in the next months? I feel like I made huge mistake and started a new job in the wrong time.**

**Location:** Bulgaria.

Comment: Congratulations on your pregnancy!

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about a project in an entirely new language taking longer, especially given that you were honest with them up front about not having experience in it.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot comment on Bulgarian employment laws. I recommend engaging an employment lawyer in Sofia.

You cannot change the contingency: pregnancy and epidemic are not going away. Focus on what you can affect.
First, the issues with C#: this might be an opportunity for you to add C# to your languages. Focus on small wins, and seek out the help of online communities and tutorials for what you struggle to learn on your own. Learning C# will make you more competitive towards a new job, and increase your value towards your current employer.

Second, the problems you listed: your colleagues are probably at least as scared as you are about the company's future, and you are probably all looking at changing job later this year. Understand this, and focus on what you can do together within the limits of the current relationships. Your top priority is your manager, who will be the one to tell the owner whether your continued employment is a good idea or not.
Moreover, you might need her/him as a reference for your next job.

So: learn C# step by step, cultivate relationships, but do assume you'll change job later this year, and prepare accordingly.
Good luck!

Comment: +1 for adding C# to her languages. @tinyheart: No matter how you perform right now, use this as a learning opportunity. In Germany trial / probation period ends with pregnancy, don't know about Bulgaria... But you will want to switch job afterwards anyway, so enjoy your time learning new technologies. And don't give yourself too much pressure. The baby's the most important thing right now, and afterwards the next job will be better :-) And hopefully Covid-19 will be over by then, too.

Answer (score 4):

I would scratch off the maternity leave (unless things are different in Bulgaria) as a reason for contract ending. I would worry about the cutoff but seems like you survived, I mean, newbies are the first to be cutted off.

It seems they really need the C# MVC project done, furthermore it seems there is not much people that can work on that and you are their best bet.

Now, you said you will probable fail because of lack of experience. You can tell them it will take you more than they think for this reason. Probably they will just tell you to make your best and in 6 months you will be more experienced and valuable.

Still, You Will have to work more time to meet the schedule. It sounds like a real challenge.

Comment: In the long term, employees who will turn to what needs doing in difficult times, and do their best even if it is not their specialty, are extremely valuable.